# Javascript async function is waiting for response without await

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to the concept of JavaScript's asynchronous behavior.

The below code is confusing me. According to my concept function b should return before the wait function finishes executing because I am not telling it wait using 'await'.
But the output I am getting is this : 
before
***then it waits for 6 seconds***
after
after b

expected output : 
before
after
after b
***without waiting for 6 seconds***
Here is the code :

```
function wait(ms)
{

  var start = new Date().getTime();

  var end = start;

  while(end < start + ms) {    

    end = new Date().getTime();

    }
}

async function b () {
  console.log('before');
  wait(6000);
  console.log('after');
}

async function c () {
b()
console.log('after b');
}

c();
```

Please help me understand this concept better

Comment: The reason it waits is because the loop inside the `wait` function is a "busy loop". It ties up the active "thread", so there is no pause for async code to jump in.

Comment: I'm confused on this expected output:
`before after after b without waiting for 6 seconds`
There should always be a pause of 6 seconds between `before` and `after`. `before b`, however, might show up in different places depending on the wait method used.

Comment: @cleberz as per my knowledge (and I may be wrong so please correct me if I am) after b prints 'before' the execution thread will move on to execute wait function but as b is async function so 'after' will print immediately.
to stop this we need to use await so we are telling the execution thread to wait until response comes back from the wait function

Comment: The `async` keyword does not make a function async. The only thing it does is allow you to use the `await` keyword within the function (the `await` keyword is invalid everywhere else)

Comment: @slebetman ok now I got it. so how and when to decide that one call will be an async call or not?Thanks for the answer bdw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy to understand. The function `wait()` is synchronous.

The `async` keyword does not make a function async. It only allows you to use the `await` keyword within a function marked with `async`.

---

So how can you know if a function is asynchronous of synchronous? The easiest way is to read the docs.

Javascript has almost no features that can signal to you if a function is synchronous or asynchronous. Not even the existence of callbacks is a signal. For example, `Array.prototype.sort()` accepts a callback but is fully synchronous. The `async` keyword is a good step in the right direction that can signal that a function is asynchronous but as you yourself have demonstrated it depends on the author of the function understanding what the `async` keyword does.

The upside is that documentation in javascript tend to be extremely good unlike other languages like Java or C++ because generally there's no automatic documentation (even if you use automatic documentation system in js you need to manually write the comments for it). There is a general culture of writing detailed, clear documentation in README files so that npm picks it up for users of libraries.

---

So how can one write an async function in javascript?

Generally there are only two ways to do it:

1. Use an async function. For example `setTimeout()` or `fetch()`:

   ```
   function waitOneSecond () {
       return new Promise(functionn (ok,err) {
           setTimeout(ok,1000);
       });
   }
   ```
2. Write it in C. For node.js you can use the Addons API to implement modules in C/C++ (https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), Chrome has NaCl (https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) etc. It's how functions like `setTimeout()`, `fetch()` etc were implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function.

As said, the `async` keyword allow you to use await. It technically does a bit more but lets leave that out for now.

The example shows a `Promise` (which does allow asynchronous programming) for which the `async` function `await`s to resolve before it continuous. Basically, `await` allows you to write synchronous code while dealing with asynchronous functions.

Try to play with the example (for instance remove await). This will result in the code not to wait for the promise and return the promise instead of the promise's resolve value.

If you want to dive into asynchronous programming your best bet is to dive into `Promise`s. These provide you the interfaces to do so.

The concept is fairly simple. You do some work and call a callback (either resolve when success, or reject on failure) when done. Understanding the interface might be a little more difficult but MDN has great documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.